# Java JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm trying to expose C++ functionality to Java using JNI. I'm trying to get a simple message box to show up first, just to make sure everything works. However, I'm getting an UnsatisfiedLinkError exception being thrown (the exception is being thrown when I call the function, not)

Java class (project cpplib):

```
package src;

public class MessageBox {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("cpplib");
    }

    private static native void libf_show(String message, String caption);

    public static void show(String message, String caption) {
        libf_show(message, caption);
    }
}
```

*Note: the folder of `cpplib`, the DLL, has been added into the native libraries path*

C++ header `messagebox.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

#include "jni.h"

extern "C"
{
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_cpplib_src_MessageBox_show(JNIEnv *env, jstring jstr_message, jstring jstr_caption);
}
```

C++ source `messagebox.cpp`:

```
#include "messagebox.hpp"
#include <windows.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_cpplib_src_MessageBox_show(JNIEnv *env, jstring jstr_message, jstring jstr_caption)
{
    const char *message = env->GetStringUTFChars(jstr_message, 0);
    const char *caption = env->GetStringUTFChars(jstr_caption, 0);

    MessageBox(NULL, message, caption, MB_OK);

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstr_message, message);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstr_caption, caption);
}
```

Full error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: src.MessageBox.libf_show(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
at src.MessageBox.libf_show(Native Method)
at src.MessageBox.show(MessageBox.java:11)
at src.CPPLIB_Test.main(CPPLIB_Test.java:6)
```

I believe I'm using the 64-bit version of the JDK (as a 32-bit DLL didn't work), so I'm using the appropriate 64-bit JDK headers (if they are different at all).

Why doesn't Java like my DLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem but I get different header. If a recreate your `MessageBox.java` inside a `src` directory and compile with `javac -d build src/MessageBox.java` and finally obtain C/C++ headers with `javah -d include -classpath build src.MessageBox`

Then, I got this method signature

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_src_MessageBox_libf_1show (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring, jstring);
```

instead

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_cpplib_src_MessageBox_show(JNIEnv *env, jstring jstr_message, jstring jstr_caption);
```

How are you creating your C++ header? maybe here it is the problem.

Comment: I was just creating it by hand according to the naming "rules" at https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html. I did, however, manage to make it work by not using a private proxy function (for some reason it generates the same header, which doesn't work) then generating the header using javah. I'll just consult javah for now on. Thanks!